# Android java.lang.VerifyError with exp4j Libraries

Tags: android, libraries, verifyerror, mathematical-expressions

I tried to make my own small calculator, but I don't want to make all the business logic by myself. So I tried to use the `javax.script` since I heard that the `javax.script` needs a real JVM and is a JavaScriptParser. Then, I searched for other libraries with the functions I needed and found the project "exp4j". First, I made a small normal Java Project with JDK 1.7, and yes, it works with the source code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownFunctionException, UnparsableExpressionException {
    ExpressionBuilder builder=new ExpressionBuilder("34*2");
    Calculable calc=builder.build();
    System.out.println(calc.calculate());
}
```

Then, I tried the same code in my model (MVC Pattern) of my calculator:

```
public void berechnen() throws UnknownFunctionException, UnparsableExpressionException {
    ExpressionBuilder builder=new ExpressionBuilder("34*2");
    Calculable calc=builder.build();
    setErgebnis(calc.calculate());
}
```

But every time I got the same exception:

> "AndroidRuntime(630): java.lang.VerifyError",

after I started the app. I can't click on the button that runs the method `berechnen()` because the app crashes after I start it.

I'm confused why my program doesn't work. When I delete all imports of exp4j and delete the source for the calculation, my calculator works fine.

My only idea is that the exp4j libaries is using a class or method that does not exist in Android.

Thank you.

Comment: You may have include jars twice, check once in libs folder and libraries in properties, I have faced same in the past

Comment: Here is a screenshot. I think I dont have twice?! http://s1.directupload.net/images/130426/k7yytynt.jpg

Comment: Remove that in the libraries and paste freshly in your res/lib folder of android application project and then clear your project

Comment: Thank you ;) that worked. Sorry for that question, I dont used other libs since today.

Comment: I'll post answer, mark that as answer by clicking the right checkbox beside that answer. to help the others.

Answer (score 3):

You may have include jars twice, check once in libs folder and libraries in properties, I have faced same in the past What you need to do is to
Remove that in the libraries and paste freshly in your `res/lib` folder of android application project and then clear your project